# SVN - how to delete files with certain extensions in an SVN repo?

Tags: svn

I have a project under source control (Tortoise SVN under Windows 7). The server, also Windows, FWIW, is a VisualSVN-Server, I believe.

I now found that some files which are under source control, should be removed from source control.

So, instead of deleting every single of these files I would like to do a
del /s (so to say) in the root of the repo that way eliminating all the respective files with one strike.

How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to delete my post but since I solved it myself I'll leave the answer here:

I checked out the whole project to my local disk, deleted the respective files and then committed the whole project again.